# Differnce from first value in pivot Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following data :

```
val df = Seq(("Central" , "Copy Paper" , "Benjamin Ross" , "$15.58" , "$3.91" , "126"),
     |       ("East" , "Copy Paper" , "Catherine Rose" , "$12.21" , "$0.08"  ,"412"),
     |       ("West" ,"Copy Paper" , "Patrick O'Brill" , "$2,756.66" , "$1,629.98" ,"490"),
     |       ("Central" , "Business Envelopes" , "John Britto" , "$212.74" , "$109.66" , "745"),
     |       ("East" , "Business Envelopes" , "xyz" , "$621" , "$721" ,"812")).toDF("Region" , "Product" , "Customer" , "Sales",  "Cost" , "Autonumber")
```

df.show()

```
+-------+------------------+---------------+---------+---------+----------+
| Region|           Product|       Customer|    Sales|     Cost|Autonumber|
+-------+------------------+---------------+---------+---------+----------+
|Central|        Copy Paper|  Benjamin Ross|   $15.58|    $3.91|       126|
|   East|        Copy Paper| Catherine Rose|   $12.21|    $0.08|       412|
|   West|        Copy Paper|Patrick O'Brill|$2,756.66|$1,629.98|       490|
|Central|Business Envelopes|    John Britto|  $212.74|  $109.66|       745|
|   East|Business Envelopes|            xyz|     $621|     $721|       812|
+-------+------------------+---------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

You can see that For Business Envelopes product , there is no data with regard to West. If there was data for West , the result would not have been null. Since there is no data pivoting with region resulted in null values which I want it to be 0 , so it can be subtracted from the first(sum(Autonumber)) and a value can be obtained. Instead now it returns a null. If in some way I can get data for Central in the group by query , things would be much simpler.

I tried the following query :

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM (SELECT region r, product as p, SUM(Autonumber) - first(sum(Autonumber)) over ( partition by product order by product , region) as new  from test1 group by r , p order by p,r) test1 pivot (sum(new) for r in ('Central' Central , 'East' East, 'West' West))").show
```

This was the data that I got

```
+------------------+-------+-----+-----+
|                 p|Central| East| West|
+------------------+-------+-----+-----+
|Business Envelopes|    0.0| 67.0| null|
|        Copy Paper|    0.0|286.0|364.0|
+------------------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Where I expected it to be this way..

```
+------------------+-------+-----+------+
|                 p|Central| East|  West|
+------------------+-------+-----+------+
|Business Envelopes|       | 67.0|-745.0|
|        Copy Paper|       |286.0| 364.0|
+------------------+-------+-----+------+
```

This is nothing but pivot on region with sum(autonumber) and then subtracting from the first value.

Any suggestions on what can be done to get -745 instead of null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that's not possible with this way.
Instead I pivoted the dataset and then subtracted from the first value.

```
spark.sql("select p , coalesce(Central , 0) - null as Central , coalesce(East,0) - coalesce(central,0) as East , coalesce(West , 0) - coalesce(central,0) as West from (SELECT * FROM (SELECT region r, product as p, SUM(Autonumber) as new  from test group by r , p order by p) test pivot (sum(new) for r in ('Central' Central ,'East' East, 'West' West)))").show
```